# why using a ifstream object twice causes error?

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

I want to output the times that a words occurs in a text and output the lines that contains the word, but when I output `vector[*beg]` I found that vector is empty!

I think the problem lie in using `ifstream &ifs` twice:

```
auto wordMap=setMap(ifs);
std::vector<std::string> vvector = read_to_vector(ifs);
```

If I exchange the two statements, it broke down immediately

I want to know where the problem lies and how to solve.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::string> read_to_vector(std::ifstream &ifs)
{
    std::string lines;
    std::vector<std::string> sentences;
    while (std::getline(ifs, lines))
    {
        sentences.push_back(lines);
    }
    return sentences;
}


std::map<std::string,std::set<size_t>> setMap(std::ifstream &ifs)
{
    std::vector<std::string> word_vector = read_to_vector(ifs);
    std::string lines, words;
    std::map < std::string, std::set<size_t> > word_map;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < word_vector.size(); i++)
    {
        //i is the current line_num
        std::istringstream stream(word_vector[i]);
        while (stream >> words)
        {
            word_map[words].insert(i);
        }
    }
    return word_map;
}
void print(std::ifstream &ifs)
{
    auto wordMap=setMap(ifs);
    std::vector<std::string> vvector = read_to_vector(ifs);
    std::string search;
    std::cout << "please input the word that you wanna search" << "\n";
    std::cin >> search;
    auto findw = wordMap.find(search);
    if (findw != wordMap.cend())
        std::cout << search << " occurs " << findw->second.size() 
                  << " times : " << std::endl;
    std::set<size_t> lineNum = findw->second;
    //it is a set
    auto beg = lineNum.begin();
    while (beg != lineNum.end())
    {
        std::cout << *beg;
        //std::cout<<vvector[*beg];
        beg++;
    }   
    for (auto c : vvector)
        std::cout << c << std::endl;

    if (vvector.empty())
        std::cout << "vector is empty!";
    //WTF!!! vector is empty!!!
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("text.txt",std::ios::in);
    print(ifs);
    ifs.close();
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just send the `std::vector<std::string>` into the `setMap` as an added reference argument and populate it rather than something to be thrown away? For that matter, is it even *really* needed in the first place?

Comment: have you checked the return value from ifs.open?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `read_to_vector` for first time (in `setMap`) it reaches to the end of file, so when next time you call it(in `print`), vector will be empty. reset the cursor before reading the lines in `read_to_vector`. Change it to:

```
std::vector<std::string> read_to_vector(std::ifstream &ifs)
{
   ifs.seekg (0, ifs.beg);//add this
   std::string lines;
   std::vector<std::string> sentences;
   while (std::getline(ifs, lines))
   {
      sentences.push_back(lines);
   }
   return sentences;
}
```

**Suggestion**

I think it's better read the file once and then pass the vector around:

```
std::map<std::string,std::set<size_t>> setMap(std::vector<std::string> word_vector )
{
   //std::vector<std::string> word_vector = read_to_vector(ifs);
   std::string lines, words;
   std::map < std::string, std::set<size_t> > word_map;
   //some code
}
```

and then

```
void print(std::ifstream &ifs)
{
    std::vector<std::string> vvector = read_to_vector(ifs);
    auto wordMap=setMap(vvector);

    // some code
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you help and think it right, but it is still not working when I added that. Can you give any further help?Thx a lot!

Comment: What you mean by not working? Gives an error? On side note, why you are reading the file multiple times, why not read it once, and then pass the vector to other methods?

Comment: What I want to say now is REALLY REALLY thanks! I have had that thought, but you know, I just gave it up. Thanks a lot! (and forgive my poor English)